# Openstack: An error occurred authenticating. Please try again later

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

I've installed & re-installed Openstack following (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/single-install.html) on an Ubuntu 14.04 distribution and after being logged in the dashboard, suddenly I lose access (webpage freezes) and I cannot log in again ("An error occurred authenticating. Please try again later."). Keystone & Dashboard appear to be started according to the Openstack installer.

Answer (score 0):

Share the keystone logs which can help us to debug the issue.

Restarting keystone service often helps in such situations if there is not any serious issue.